# How to release the objects which are in Xib in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my .h file create 3 objects like below

```
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
IBOutlet UITextView *txtMessage;
IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

In xib  make Connection for all 3 objects
  hierarchy in xib like

```
**View 
       ---UIScrollView
            ---UITextView
            ---UIWebView**
```

then I am printing retainCount in dealloc method

```
NSLog(@"scrollView retainCount:%d",[scrollView retainCount]);
    [scrollView release];scrollView=nil;
NSLog(@"txtMessage retainCount:%d",[txtMessage retainCount]);
    [txtMessage release];txtMessage=nil;
NSLog(@"webView retainCount:%d",[webView retainCount]);
    [webView release];webView=nil;
```

on console i am getting like below

```
scrollView retainCount:3
txtMessage retainCount:2
webView retainCount:2
```

I want to know why its happens like this  ,and one more thing how can release this objects in dealloc method...

Comment: Number 1 rule in memory management: if you did not retain/alloc it, do not release it. In your case, you do not need to do anything. Do not fuss over retainCounts. Just balance your retain/init with autorelease/release in your code and you will not run into problems.

Comment: Did you set properties in three views?

Comment: if run my app with performance toll if i go to detail page memeory allocation increasing .90 MB  and come back to main view its not decreasing to old allocation .if  i release the above three objects in dealloc method allocation memory reducing

Comment: retainCount is useless.  Don't call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: you don't release them. You didn't alloc] init] then, they're not your responsibility memory-wise.
The only case where they're somehow your responsibility, is when you retain them using a @property (retain) for the IBOutlets. In that case, you'll release them in [dealloc]

Answering to your comment in another answer about instruments and releasing the outlets that the xib creates: if you release them, then the view will be unload sometime and the responsible for releasing the elements in the .xib (which it wasn't you) will release them again, and it will crash ;) The reason why you go back to another view and the memory doesn't decrease is because when a view disappears, it's not unloaded, that only happens when either the view controller is deallocated, or when the application gets a memory warning.

Comment: Can you explain why the retainCount is different for the objects in xib

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to do anything in dealloc. In Objective-C, if you haven't alloc/retain anything, you don't need to worry.

Comment: if run my app with performance toll if i go to detail page memeory allocation increasing .90 MB and come back to main view its not decreasing to old allocation .if i release the above three objects in dealloc method allocation memory reducing